# Animate image's saturation

Tags: android, android-animation, android-image, android-transitions

Is it possible to animate the saturation of an image (e.g. png) over time? For example from grayscale to full color. Plus if I can use an Interpolator.

I have seen the EffectFactory and the ColorMatrix classes but I cannot combine them with an animation/transition.

E.g. applying grayscale saturation on a `Drawable drawable`:

```
ColorMatrix matrix = new ColorMatrix();
matrix.setSaturation(0);

ColorMatrixColorFilter filter = new ColorMatrixColorFilter(matrix);
drawable.setColorFilter(filter);
```

and for full saturation later:

```
matrix.setSaturation(1);
```

---

For anyone interested my full solution based on Simon's answer:

```
final ColorMatrix matrix = new ColorMatrix();
final Drawable drawable = ... ;

ValueAnimator animation = ValueAnimator.ofFloat(0f, 1f);
animation.setDuration(1000);
//   animation.setInterpolator();
animation.addUpdateListener(new ValueAnimator.AnimatorUpdateListener() {
    @Override
    public void onAnimationUpdate(ValueAnimator animation) {
        matrix.setSaturation(animation.getAnimatedFraction());
        ColorMatrixColorFilter filter = new ColorMatrixColorFilter(matrix);
        drawable.setColorFilter(filter);
    }
});
animation.start();
```

Comment: Post the code you're using to apply a custom saturation value on the image

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It certainly could be achieved with a ValueAnimator:

```
ValueAnimator animation = ValueAnimator.ofFloat(0f, 1f);
animation.setDuration(1000);
animation.addUpdateListener(new AnimatorUpdateListener() {
    @Override
    public void onAnimationUpdate(ValueAnimator animation) {
        matrix.setSaturation(animation.getAnimatedFraction());
    }
});
animation.start();
```

Comment: That was simple. Thanks for the snippet!

Answer (score 0):

You have to animate it yourself!

Should not be that hard.

See the `ColorMatrix` example in the API's demos folder.

http://alvinalexander.com/java/jwarehouse/android-examples/platforms/android-2/samples/ApiDemos/src/com/example/android/apis/graphics/ColorMatrixSample.java.shtml

You can extend `Drawable` and increment a value in the onDraw method and then set the filter accordingly.

You get the animation by calling `invalidate()` every few ms in `onDraw`. Be sure to slow down the iterations  by puting the thread to sleep. `Thread.sleep(40);` for 25 fps